# How to install packages

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm having trouble installing both packages MicrobiomeSeq and

```
MicrobiomeUtilities, it keeps saying: 
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘microbiomeSeq’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for microbiomeutilities](https://microsud.github.io/microbiomeutilities/) suggests the following instead of `install.packages`:

```r
> install.packages("devtools")
> devtools::install_github("microsud/microbiomeutilities")
```